# Two controllers with common factory and ng-repeat refresh

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I've problem with AngularJS. Ng-repeat dosn't want to refresh loop when I add new item to JSON from another instance of controller

In first controller I set JSON

```
(function(){
    'use strict';
    angular.module('mainApp').controller('ListController', function($scope, FavoriteListService) {

    $scope.addToFavorites = function(speaker){
            FavoriteListService.setFavorites(speaker);
        };
})();
```

In secound controller I have to display ng-repeat

```
 (function(){
        'use strict';
        angular.module('mainApp').controller('ShowController', function($scope, FavoriteListService) {
    $scope.favoritesList = FavoriteListService.getFavorites();
  })();
```

Factory

```
(function () {
    'use strict';
    angular.module('mainApp').factory('FavoriteListService', function () {
        var obj = {};

        obj.getFavorites = function () {
            var favorites = localStorage.getItem('speaker-favorites');
            if (favorites == null) {
                favorites = {};
            } else {
                favorites = JSON.parse(favorites);
            }
            return favorites;
        };

        obj.setFavorites = function (speaker) {
            var favorites = obj.getFavorites();
                favorites[speaker.uid] = {firstname: speaker.firstname, name: speaker.name};
            localStorage.setItem('speaker-favorites', JSON.stringify(favorites));
        };
        return obj;
    });
})();
```

Template:

```
 <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="(key, fav) in favoritesList">
            {{fav.firstname}} {{fav.name}}
        </li>
    </ul>
```

Everything is fine, when set & display is in one controller.

If I want to use 2 controllers (or 2 instance of 1 controller) ng-repeat show correctly all items after load page, but when I add new item it doesn't refresh loop and doesn't show new item.

Is any method to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You either need to change repeater to (and assign that FavoriteListService to $scope variable):

```
ng-repeat="(key, fav) in FavoriteListService.getFavorites()"
```

or $watch that favorite list in your controller like that:

```
$scope.$watch(
  function() { return FavoriteListService.getFavorites(); },
  function(newValue, oldValue) {
    if ( newValue !== oldValue ) {
      $scope.favoritesList = newValue;
    }
  },
  true
);
```

Because when you assign your service method return to scope method it's not being working like a reference.

Comment: First solution doesn't work, but secound resolved my problem. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Create an empty object, and use `angular.copy` to update the object:

```
app.factory('FavoriteListService', function () {
    var obj = {};
    //create empty object
    var favorites = {};

    obj.getFavorites = function () {
        let update = localStorage.getItem('speaker-favorites');
        if (update) {
           //Use angular copy
           angular.copy(update, favorites);
        };
        return favorites;
    };

    obj.setFavorites = function (speaker) {
        favorites[speaker.uid] = {firstname: speaker.firstname, name: speaker.name};
        localStorage.setItem('speaker-favorites', JSON.stringify(favorites));
    };
    return obj;
});
```

By using `angular.copy`, all of the controllers that use the `getFavorites` function get the same object reference and all of them see the same changes to its contents.

For more information, see [AngularJS angular.copy API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.copy)